# Passing a parameter through server.execute?

Tags: asp-classic, parameter-passing

It is possible to pass a parameter through `server.execute`?

Fx. I have in my `site.asp` an IF-scenario where I need `functions.asp?a=something&id=123` executed. Is this possible?!

On site.asp:

```
dim id
id = 123

if b = "hi" then
  server.execute("functions.asp?a=something&id=" & id)
else
  response.write("No way dude")
end if
```

On functions.asp

```
a = request.querystring("a")
id = request.querystring("id")

if a = "something" and cint(id) > 100 then
  response.write("Yes way dude")
else
  response.write("No way dude")
end if
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Serverobject error 'ASP 0173 : 80004005' Invalid character in parameter-path in the MapPath-method --- Or something alike, it is in Danish at my screen :)

Comment: And without the querystring parameters included, what happens then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use querystring in `Server.Execute`, it's clearly mentioned in the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

<strike>What you can do is much better: you can directly access the variable `id` defined in `site.asp` inside `functions.asp`, and you can also declare and set another variable, `a`:</strike>

--site.asp:

```
dim id, a
id = 123
a = "something"
server.execute("functions.asp")
```

--functions.asp

```
if a = "something" and cint(id) > 100 then
    response.write("Yes way dude")
else  
    response.write("No way dude")
end if
```

As it creates whole new "scripting environment" the executed file won't have access to the calling code properties, methods or variables, only to the global Request parameters, Session etc.

With this in mind, I fear the most simple way around is using Session variable to pass the value between pages:

```
Session("id") = 123
Session("a") = "something"
```

And then:

```
if Session("a") = "something" and Session("id") > 100 then
    response.write("Yes way dude")
else  
    response.write("No way dude")
end if
```

Comment: That was what I thought as well. But it simply doesn't work. I have tried with unique variable-names to ensure that the variable isn't overwritten. But that isn't the case either.

Comment: Could it be because it is a server.execute inside a server.execute?

Comment: What you mean "doesn't work"? What exact error you get? Never tried nested `Server.Execute` but can't see any reason why it won't work.

Comment: Well the short version is, that the variable is empty :) And I have no idea why.. The answer you posted should work in my theory as well. I will use another way instead: functions() :)

Comment: If you want, post your whole code (or shortened version reproducing only the problem) and I'll take a look. It should work. :)

Comment: -1 This is not true.  Server.Execute spins up an additional script context, it cannot share variables with the caller of Server.Execute.  Perhaps you were thinking of include files?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones true, I got confused.. edited with way around this though not ideal, it would work.

Comment: +1 Tgats better, its the only pure asp solution.  I tend to use a naming convention is the "parameters" and be removed from the seissoon after the call and are not going to collide with other names

Comment: @AnthonyWJones cheers, agree about removing from Session after use - good practice indeed.

Answer (score 3):

This question may be old and resolved, but the best answer doesn't mention everything, and there is information clearly posted on Microsoft.com about it:

---

**[Server.Execute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**

*The following collections and properties are available to the executed ASP page:*

1. ***Application variables**, even if they are set in the calling page.*
2. ***Session properties**, even if they are set in the calling page.*
3. ***Server variables and properties**, even if they are set in the calling page.*
4. ***Request collections and properties**, even if they are set in the calling page. This includes **Form** and **QueryString** data passed to the calling page.*
5. ***Response collections and properties**. The executed .asp file may modify HTTP headers. However, as with any .asp file, if the executed .asp file attempts to modify HTTP headers after it sends a response to the client, it generates an error.*

---

So as you can see, there are 5 ways Microsoft suggests to pass variables through to a `Server.Execute` method.  Before I saw this on Microsoft, the preferred method was `Session`, as the best answer suggests, since I saw this before the info on Microsoft.com. But after noticing that `QueryStrings` can be passed from the previous page, I would have to say this beats using `Session` for passing values.  `Session` would be needed if your application required you adding variables to the executing page.

But passing variables, I would say `QueryStrings`, and it's easy to apply if your application allows the flexibility.  I'm sure you know how to already use querystrings, but in the sense of using it for a `Server.Execute` method, you can simply do this:

Consider having `ASP1.asp` and `ASP2.asp`:

ASP1.asp includes:

```
 Server.Execute("ASP2.asp")
```

ASP2.asp includes:

```
 Response.Write Request("id")
```

When you call `ASP1.asp?id=123`
You will notice that ASP2.asp also see's the same `Querystring` passed to ASP1.asp, so it would write `123` on the response of ASP1.asp.

That's much less complicated than using a `Session` for the task.

Answer (score 0):

In short: YES, you can use QueryString values in conjunction with **Server.Execute** within an ASP.NET page or application.

You can pass dynamic variables in a QueryString argument assembled in the executing ASPX page (page1.aspx), as follows:

```
    Dim intExample1 As Int = 22
    Dim strExample2 As String = "hello world"
    Server.Execute("page2.aspx?number=" & intExample1 & "&string=" & Server.UrlEncode(strExample2))
```

In this example, page2.aspx can then reference and use the following values:

```
    Request.QueryString("number")
    Request.QueryString("string")
```

Comment: err, OP is asking about `classic asp`. `asp` <> `aspx`. whole other engine, as far as IIS is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `#include` instead of `server.execute`?

I looked for a difference and found that in this particular case, using `#include` is the best solution:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages/Server-Side_Includes#What_it_Does

You need some variables defined in parent page to be used in child, so your solution could be:

```
dim id, a
id = 123
a = "something"
if b = "hi" then
    <!--#include file="functions.asp" -->
else
    response.write("No way dude")
end if
```

On functions.asp

```
if a = "something" and cint(id) > 100 then
response.write("Yes way dude")
else
    response.write("No way dude")
end if
```

Advantages:

- Simply act as it was the same page.
- Use of disposal variables instead of Session variables.
- Don't show internal variables in main URL.

Comment: aren't includes hoisted like variable declarations though?

Comment: Please read "What it Does" section in the link above, it says "This allows you to import the contents of another document into the current one. This is extremely useful for reusing common blocks of ASP code and HTML", in this case variables declared in the first document will be available in the second. it's like you import the code itself and write it in the first document

Comment: but it's nothing like server.execute, which has its own memory space. also, try making a file called `run.asp` with content: `start: <% if false then %><!-- #include file="yes.asp" --><% else %><!-- #include file="no.asp" --><% end if %>:end` then in `no.asp` have `response.write "no"` and in `yes.asp` have `<script language="Javascript" runat="server">for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {Response.Write ("yes, ");}</script>` .. you will find that BOTH includes execute, regardless of the if conditional. So they are hoisted. and you have to break out of asp to do the include; doesn't work inline like you had

Comment: That's because you changed default language and used javascript instead of vb script, now try `<% Response.Write ("yes, ")%>` in `yes.asp`. this will run perfectly and it's equivalent to one file code. then try `<% if false then %> <script language="Javascript" runat="server"> for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {Response.Write ("yes, ");} </script><% else %> <%response.write "no"%><% end if %>` this last will print both, as you see there is no include.

Comment: But I use `server.execute` specifically so that I can switch to javascript, or activeperl, or some other language to execute something in separate memory space. I can already execute vbscript AND jscript in the same page in two different script tags, but not if one is inside an include. Don't you find that odd? Anyway, this isn't answering the OP's question